# Syntax error in mysql new version

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with this, and I keep getting this error

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5.

Do you have any ideas for why I keep getting this error?

```
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `prn_insert`;

 CREATE PROCEDURE `prn_insert`(id int, name text, description text)
 BEGIN

  insert into test
  select id,name,description;

 END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolon is ending the CREATE PROCEDURE statement. To get the entire statement, use a delimiter other than a semicolon. We frequently use **`$$`** (two dollar signs) as a delimiter, but you can use any character sequence that doesn't appear *within* the statement(s) you want to execute.

For example:

```
 DELIMITER $$

 DROP PROCEDURE myproc $$

 CREATE PROCEDURE myproc(arg INT)
 BEGIN
     DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
     SET i = 1;
 END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

Once the new delimiter is set, it stays in effect until it's changed to something else.  So. we usually want to set it back to semicolon immediately after the `CREATE PROCEDURE' statement.